# Clicking on “ hidden image -- click to show“ statement will show the image again and hide the statement?

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIwp8.png)

- Every time you select an image (select files from the images folder in your current folder only) and you click upload,the image will be loaded inside an empty div.
- After the image is loaded the button “upload ” should be disabled
- Width, Height, Width percentage and all buttons are initially disabled.
- Width percentage  has a drop down list contains ( 25, 50, 100) percentages options
  -Selecting “Change the pixels of width and height” will enable Width and Height and the user should specify the width and Height and click Apply to change the image size.
  -Selecting “Change percentage” will enable Width percentage and the user should specify the width and click Apply to change the image size.
- By clicking Opacity the user is able to put ONLY a number from 0 to 1. Then by clicking on Apply opacity it will change the opacity of the image.
- By clicking on Change background and click Apply color it will change the background color of the webpage.

Finally.. after the image is loaded inside the div
-Double clicking on the image will hide it and inside the div you will have a statement says“ hidden image  --  click to show“

- Clicking on “ hidden image  -- click to show“ statement will show the image again and hide the statement

Comment: Can you please tell what is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can post questions about programming problems and related tools here, but unfortunately your post does not even include a question. Please do not just post problem descriptions - try to solve the task yourself and narrow your problem. If you ask a specific question with all relevant source code included, somebody might write a helpful answer.